# How to install EventDispatcher in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to install event dispatcher.
I have downloaded composer and I have put this in `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "dev-master",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.0.*",


    **"symfony/event-dispatcher": "dev-master"**
```

But I am still not able to install it.

I get this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/cxxxxx/Symfony/app/autoload.php

Comment: Maybe try using composer autoload from vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php instead of symfony autoloader component?

Comment: If you have a Symfony project it already uses EventDispatcher component.

Comment: @zalas how can i check that , any files to look for

Comment: @user1155683 Run the following command: `php app/console container:debug | grep event_dispatcher`. If it returns something, you have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring `symfony/symfony` which includes the event-dispatcher. So adding it is not needed. Once composer is working, you will have access to it.

The actual problem however is that you're trying to use composer, but didn't adapt your `autoload.php` to use the composer autoloader.

Take a look at the [Symfony Standard Edition's `autoload.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/autoload.php). If you do things like this, you will get rid of your error.

Comment: so u mean i should replace the existing autoload.php with that code